# Squaring a $n \times n \times n$ tensor to get another $n \times n \times n$ tensor

Tags: graph-theory, tensors

I have recently been considering modelling graph walks of length 3 using a rank 3 tensor as opposed to modelling walks of length 2 with an adjacency matrix. I am interested to see what happens if you square this tensor but currently I don't know the operations for how to do that.

Is there a 3D equivalent to squaring a matrix?

edit:

Given a graph $G$ with $|V|\geq3$, model walks $x$-$y$-$z$ as $1$ in position $A_{xyz}$ of an "adjacency" tensor and $0$ otherwise.

- When squaring an adjacency matrix of some graph $G$ the output $A^2$ can be interpreted as the number of walks that can be made in 2 steps.

I'm hoping to gain some insight similar to this from squaring an adjacency tensor. I don't know what relationship would come out as that's what I am curious to see. Maybe the trace of the tensor might contain the information whether or not $K_3$ are present for each vertex.

Comment: There are many analogues to matrix multiplication for 3-tensors. Maybe you can get a meaningful answer by explaining what you want the result to represent.

Comment: @MeesdeVries That's fair. I'll amend the question.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I feel like I haven't really added anything. If the post still doesn't make sense I'll remove it.

Comment: Note that what happens under taking the square of the matrix doesn't really play well with how your tensor is set up. Note that the square of the matrix forgets through which intermediate node the path passed. If you try to do the same thing for a tensor, you could get a rank-four tensor where the value at $i, j, k, l$ counts paths that go from $i$ to $j$ to any intermediate node to $k$ to $l$, but that's awkward and probably not what you want.